# How to use replace the first occurrences of a string only if it appears more than once in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a strings that look like this:

```
problem <- c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3 & GROUP 4")
```

In between each group, there's " & ". I want to use R (either `sub()` or something from the `stringr` package) to replace every " &" with a "," when there's more than one "&" present. However, I don't want the final "&" to be changed. How would I do that so it looks like:

```
#Note: Only the 3rd and 4th strings should be changed
solution <- c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2", "GROUP 1, GROUP 2 & GROUP 3", "GROUP 1, GROUP 2, GROUP 3 & GROUP 4")
```

In the actual string, there could be an infinite number of "&"s, so I don't want to hard code a limit if possible.

Comment: `str_replace_all(problem,"&(?=.{1,30}&)",",")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use regular expressions with a lookahead assertion [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups).

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(problem, " &(?=.*?&)", ", ")
```

output:

```
[1] "GROUP 1"                              
[2] "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2"                    
[3] "GROUP 1,  GROUP 2 & GROUP 3"          
[4] "GROUP 1,  GROUP 2,  GROUP 3 & GROUP 4"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `strsplit`

```
 sapply(strsplit(problem, "\\s+&\\s+"), 
    function(x) sub(",([^,]+$)", " & \\1", toString(x)))
```

-output

```
[1] "GROUP 1"                              "GROUP 1 &  GROUP 2"                   "GROUP 1, GROUP 2 &  GROUP 3"          "GROUP 1, GROUP 2, GROUP 3 &  GROUP 4"
```

Comment: ,@akrun, Why do you get an one line output solution [1]. If I apply your code I get four lines [1]-[4]?

Comment: @TarJae it could be the width settings in your options that my be different from mine

Answer (score 3):

You can use

`\K&(?= .* & )`

The pattern matches:

- `\K` Match a space, and clear the match buffer (forget what is matched so far)
- `&` Match literally
- `(?= .* & )` Positive lookahead, assert a space to the right and another occurrence of  `&`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JlxAIO/1)

For example

```
problem <- c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3 & GROUP 4")
gsub(" \\K&(?= .* & )", ",", problem, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "GROUP 1"                              
[2] "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2"                    
[3] "GROUP 1 , GROUP 2 & GROUP 3"          
[4] "GROUP 1 , GROUP 2 , GROUP 3 & GROUP 4"
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be done using Perl mode and the \G anchor.

Insure 2 or more &'s, then match any & that has another downstream.

```
(?m)(?:^(?=.*&.*&)|(?!^)\G)[^&\n]*\K&(?=.*&)
```

Replace with comma `,`

https://regex101.com/r/Mtvopf/1

```
 (?m)
 (?:
    ^ 
    (?= .* & .* & )
  | (?! ^ )
    \G 
 )
 [^&\n]* \K &
 (?= .* & )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
str_replace_all(problem," &", ",") %>% 
  str_replace(", (GROUP [0-9])$", " & \\1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```r
problem <- c("GROUP 1", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3", "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2 & GROUP 3 & GROUP 4")
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(problem, "\\s*&\\s*(?=[^&]*&)", ", ")
```

**Results**:

```r
[1] "GROUP 1"                             "GROUP 1 & GROUP 2"                  
[3] "GROUP 1, GROUP 2 & GROUP 3"          "GROUP 1, GROUP 2, GROUP 3 & GROUP 4"
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoPyknNVfBRlchWUPJPcg/NEDBUElHAcZUUFOAsIywCsJZxgSk4SwTJU2unMykosSiSo3ikqLMvPQiTS4gI74otSAnMTk1PjEnRwPqKqCRMTHFWmogQsPeNjpOLVZLTRNkExBp/v8PAA).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  &                        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^&]*                    any character except: '&' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    &                        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```